# Implement a typed restricted property

Tags: c#, oop

Two classes: A & B, each of which have a MyProp property.

The MyProp property of A can only be of A type. The MyProp property of B can either be of A or B type.

To implement this I thought about creating an interface IBase containing a property MyProp of type IBase and make A & B implement it.

The problem in this case is that A could have a MyProp of type B, so it's not an option.

I could remove the MyProp property from the interface and create a type A property in A and IBase in B but I feel that it's not a proper solution because both types have a MyProp property that works the same way so I feel that the property should be handled higher in the hierarchy.

I thought also about a generic abstract base class that have a property MyProp of its generic type but for the B type the generic type would be an infinitely recursive type:

```
ABase<ABase<ABase<...>>>
```

Is there a proper way to achieve this in C#?

**Edit**: changed the name of the property so there's no confusion anymore

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is multiple inheritance which is not allowed in C#

Comment: @Sphaso When I'm talking about Parent it's the name of the property, not the Parent class

Comment: Yes, but one property can have only one type. Even using generics you cannot really have one property which type is restricted on two types.

Comment: ..."create a type A property in A and IBase in B"... bingo.  You got it.

Comment: @Dan-o this is the only way to do it? As I said in my question I feel that this solution is not a proper solution

Comment: Well I don't recognize your feelings as a valid measure of "properness".  Perhaps if you were to quantify your feelings we could help you.

Comment: @nkoniishvt Are you looking for way so that B can have MyProp sometimes of type A and sometimes of type B? If yes you can create B as generic visit this fiddle and you will feel intellisense https://dotnetfiddle.net/eqT5SW :)

Comment: @Dan-o Object oriented programming is all about factoring things highest possible in the hierarchy, Object class contains all functions such a basic object can contain and so on. The Parent property of my two classes works the same way and it feels wrong not to handle them the same way (higher in hierarchy).

Comment: Well, good luck with your feelings.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya it's close but the property will always be either A or B, never an int or anything like that so in the B class the generic type will be infinitely recursive.

Comment: @nkoniishvt I added int as just a dummy end so that it does not be recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this problem is likely to be solved nicely "at compile time" so to speak. But I think, you should make some common ancestor for A and B, make both properties of that type and control type validity in property setters by raising an exception on incorrect type detection.

If your code is properly tested, the fact, that the incorrect assignment can only be detected at runtime should not matter much.

Comment: Thank you. This solution seems to me to be the correct way to achieve this (I may be wrong to think so)